# how can we replicate hive nested structs in snowflake?

Tags: hive, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have nested struct data in DB I need to migrate that to snowflake how can I replicate that nested struct in snowflake. In snowflake I don't have struct data type it is only variant.

Comment: Please provide some sample data. Does the fact that you have nested data in Hive have any bearing on how the data needs to be stored in Snowflake? If it does, what are your requirements/constraints?

Answer (score 0):

so google finds:

https://gist.github.com/irajhedayati/c595e349d68b7a5074da81f1b8c6eec5

which has some code like:

```
INSERT into calls_nested
SELECT
    '5' AS call_id, 
    'Jack' AS name, 
    45 AS age, 
    named_struct('first_name', 'Joe', 'last_name', 'Doe') AS account, 
    named_struct('home', '514-111-2222', 'work', '514-333-4444') AS phone_directory,
    array(
        named_struct('street', '1 Guy', 'city', 'Montreal'),
        named_struct('street', '1 McGill', 'city', 'Montreal')
    ) AS addresses;
```

`named_struct` -> `object_construct`
`array` -> `array_construct`

and you just keep stacking them if that's what you want.

```
SELECT
    '5' AS call_id, 
    'Jack' AS name, 
    45 AS age, 
    object_construct('first_name', 'Joe', 'last_name', 'Doe') AS account, 
    object_construct('home', '514-111-2222', 'work', '514-333-4444') AS phone_directory,
    array_construct(
        object_construct('street', '1 Guy', 'city', 'Montreal'),
        object_construct('street', '1 McGill', 'city', 'Montreal')
    ) AS addresses,
    object_construct('call_id', call_id, 'name', name, 'age' ,age, 'account', account, 'phone_directory', phone_directory, 'addresses',addresses) as object_of_objects
    ;
```

| CALL_ID | NAME | AGE | ACCOUNT | PHONE_DIRECTORY | ADDRESSES | OBJECT_OF_OBJECTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Jack | 45 | { "first_name": "Joe", "last_name": "Doe" } | { "home": "514-111-2222", "work": "514-333-4444" } | [ { "city": "Montreal", "street": "1 Guy" }, { "city": "Montreal", "street": "1 McGill" } ] | { "account": { "first_name": "Joe", "last_name": "Doe" }, "addresses": [ { "city": "Montreal", "street": "1 Guy" }, { "city": "Montreal", "street": "1 McGill" } ], "age": 45, "call_id": "5", "name": "Jack", "phone_directory": { "home": "514-111-2222", "work": "514-333-4444" } } |